# Spring form with nested objects throws target object binding error

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a Spring form with my controller and the entity it is mapping to has nested objects. When try to hit the page with the form it throws the below error.

Am I not initializing the model correctly?

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payPal2",
        headers = "Accept=application/json",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
Payment payByCreditCard2(@ModelAttribute("orderContext") OrderContext orderContext, Model model) throws Exception {
    PaymentWithCreditCard paymentWithCreditCard = new PaymentWithCreditCardImpl();
    model.addAttribute("billingAddress", new Address());

    OTHER Setters and getters down here
```

The form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="orderContext" method="post" action="/service/payments/payPal2">
    <form:input path="billingAddress.city"/>
</form:form>
```

The error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /paypalTest.jsp at line 14

11: </head>
12: <body>
13: <form:form modelAttribute="orderContext" method="post" action="/service/payments/payPal2">
14:     <form:input path="billingAddress.city"/>
15: </form:form>
16: </body>
17: </html>

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'orderContext' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.paypalTest_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(paypalTest_jsp.java:151)
    org.apache.jsp.paypalTest_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(paypalTest_jsp.java:116)
    org.apache.jsp.paypalTest_jsp._jspService(paypalTest_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Order Context:

```
import com.paypal.api.payments.*;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Address;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderContext {
    private com.paypal.api.payments.Address billingAddress;
    private CreditCard creditCard;
    private Details details;
    private Amount amount;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    private List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstruments;
    private Payer payer;
    private Payment payment;

    public Address getBillingAddress() {
        return billingAddress;
    }

    public void setBillingAddress(Address billingAddress) {
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public CreditCard getCreditCard() {
        return creditCard;
    }

    public void setCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard) {
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Amount getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Amount amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public List<FundingInstrument> getFundingInstruments() {
        return fundingInstruments;
    }

    public void setFundingInstruments(List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstruments) {
        this.fundingInstruments = fundingInstruments;
    }

    public Payer getPayer() {
        return payer;
    }

    public void setPayer(Payer payer) {
        this.payer = payer;
    }

    public Payment getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(Payment payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderContext{" +
                "billingAddress=" + billingAddress +
                ", creditCard=" + creditCard +
                ", details=" + details +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", transactions=" + transactions +
                ", fundingInstruments=" + fundingInstruments +
                ", payer=" + payer +
                ", payment=" + payment +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: plz share the OrderContext implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to create two methods in your controllers: one that handles the display of the form (GET), and the other one that handles the form once submitted (POST).

You're only using the POST method, i.e. when receiving the form data once submitted.

```java
// just displays the form
@RequestMapping(value = "/payPal2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String payByCreditCardGet(@ModelAttribute("orderContext") OrderContext orderContext, Model model) throws Exception {
    // orderContext is "empty", just need to return the JSP path to the form
    return "paypal/index"; // for example
}

// receives the form
@RequestMapping(value = "/payPal2", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Payment payByCreditCardPost(@ModelAttribute("orderContext") OrderContext orderContext, Model model) throws Exception {
    // form is submitted, orderContext is set depending on the form entries
}
```

Comment: this is the only view I will be returning besides index since everything else is being handled by AngularJS.  Is there a way that I can do this without returning a view on the GET request?  If I have to switch from (@)ModelAttribute to (@)ResponseBody, that is fine.

Comment: This answer is correct per the question asked.  I ended up moving to (@)RequestBody, though since I could just pass up json.  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The method from which you are redirecting to form, add your `OrderContext` object in request scope like this :

```
@RequestMapping(ur_mapping_url)
public String loadForm(Model model){
  model.addAttribute(new OrderContext());
  return "formPage_name";
}
```

Comment: The `@ModelAttribute` annotation automatically adds the concerned parameter as an attribute of the model.

Comment: @sp00m : Before going to the form page, he needs to put the object instance in request scope. `@ModelAttribute` will be used to fetch the model from jsp page to your controller..

Comment: This can also be done using the annotation: the annotated parameter will be automatically instantiated if not already bound by a submitted form.